# Starting Kyma after successful installation

Tags: kubectl, minikube, kyma

How do you start kyma after successful installation?

I've just used the command `minikube start`

However it gives me below error and kubernetes dashboard can't running

```
E0912 09:36:59.179484    5806 start.go:305] Error restarting cluster:  restarting kube-proxy: waiting for kube-proxy to be up for configmap update: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Successful installation actually means minikube is already started. Look into https://kyma-project.io/docs/latest/root/kyma#prerequisites and note about usual `minikube start` vs our run.sh script

> To work with Kyma, use only the provided installation and deinstallation scripts. Kyma does not work on a basic Minikube cluster that you can start using the minikube start command or stop with the minikube stop command. If you don't need Kyma on Minikube anymore, remove the cluster with the minikube delete command.

After successful installation, minikube is started, kubectl configured to use the minikube cluster, you can do `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and check if all pods are Ready